# translate arm instructions to hex

Tags: x86, arm, patching, binary-editing

I looking for simple tool(not site) to translate arm instruction to hex like http://armconverter.com/.

Without linker , I want put 1 instruction , and want get the hex .

Do you know one please?

Answer (score 5):

as i commented to Elians post rasm2 works in windows as is

**rasm2 -a arm -b 32 "add r0, r1, r2"** will return  **020081e0**

you can use **[keystone](http://www.keystone-engine.org) / [capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/)** to assemble and disassemble

```
:\>python
>>> from keystone import *
>>> for i in (Ks(KS_ARCH_ARM,KS_MODE_ARM).asm ("add R0,R1,R2" , 0x400000) )[0]:
...     print "%02x " % i
...
02
00
81
e0
>>>
```

or if you have visual studio you can compile and dumpbin a single instruction

```
:\>cat foo.asm
    AREA .text, CODE, ARM
test PROC
    add R0,R1,R2
    ENDP
    END

:\>armasm /nologo foo.asm

:\>dumpbin /disasm foo.obj | grep add
  00000000: EB01 0002 add         r0,r1,r2
```

with keystone you use KS_MODE_THUMB 
with rasm you should be using -b 16 but it seems there is a bug where rasm2 can disassemble hex pairs correctly but not assemble it back again

so may be you follow it up in github issues for radare2

```
>>> from keystone import *
>>> for i in (Ks(KS_ARCH_ARM , KS_MODE_THUMB).asm("add r0,r1,r2" , 0 ))[0]:
...     print "%02x " %i ,
...
01  eb  02  00
>>> ^Z


C:\>rasm2 -a arm -b 16 -d "01 eb 02 00"
add.w r0, r1, r2

C:\>rasm2 -a arm -b 16 add.w r0, r1, r2
Cannot assemble 'add.w' at line 3
invalid
```

Comment: I have little misunderstanding, and will happy if you can help me , .  I want the simple way to get each time the hex for 1 arm instruction .  `1)how can I install  rasm2  n windows that I can run `rasm2 -a arm -b 32 "add r0, r1, r2"`    2) what is the different between keystone  and keypatch? thank you

Comment: what is the problem with installing  double click the installer is all that is needed :(  http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.3.0/radare2_installer-msvc_32-2.3.0.exe  i dont know what keypatch is it is for ida and i havent used it keystone can be installed with pip install keystone

Answer (score 2):

For this exact purpose I highly suggest using a command line tool such as rasm2.

It is a tool that comes with the radare2 suite. One of it's basic capabilities is translating assembly instructions in various architectures to opcodes and vice versa.
The usage is fairly simple:

```
# rasm2 -a arm -b 32 "add R0, R1, R2"
020081e0
```

Here:

`-a` specifies the architecture.

`-b` specifies the bits (where 16 is Thumb-1)

For more information there is plenty, such as the [radare2 blog](http://radare.today/posts/rasm/) and [official book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/rasm2/intro.html).

Comment: how can I do it on windows please?

Comment: @ivn23744sawoe.com it technically can be done but it is experimental (refer to https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/introduction/windows_compilation.html) however, I highly suggest using cygwin or something similar to get the best out of it (I believe also listed in the link above. Also, this question may be too broad or subjective I'd suggest limiting the scope for "offline windows command line tool' or something similar to improve it's quality.

Comment: so you not recommend use radare2 on wondows? I once download from https://rada.re/r/  ... do you only recommend use on Linux and install with `sudo apt-get install radare2` and then translate with `rasm2 -a arm -b 32 add R0, R1, R2` ??

Comment: @ivn23744sawoe.com In general, if you have a Debian distro then yes, I suggest using it. If not you can get a similar result using Cygwin (https://cygwin.com/) on windows and installing radare2 on it (or on a VM).

Comment: I can use Ubuntu . are you sure that `sudo apt-get install radare2` need to install all I need to run `rasm2 -a arm -b 32 add R0, R1, R2` ?  I not meat and use Cygwin , can't I just install radare2 on windows without Cygwin  ?

Comment: @ivn23744sawoe.com Yes it works on Ubuntu as you said. It can also work on windows as stated in the documentation earlier. Please try the methods yourself and see what works for you instead of positing it as a comment here. Still this is a Q&A site, not a technical support forum :)

Comment: @ op rasm2 works on windows   @ElianKamal  you need to add quotes iirc 80e0 corresponds to add r0, r0 , r0 not what you want you need to get back 02008e01