# Capstone in reverse mode

Tags: assembly, capstone

I am using capstone in python in order to dissassemble binary instructions.

Is there a way to work in the reverse mode ? I mean typing some asm instructions and ask capstone (in python) to generate binary  (I mean raw binary, whithout ELF or PE)

Comment: You need http://www.keystone-engine.org/.

Comment: You should better use tools such as `rasm2` than Keystone. Except if you want to code something fully automatized (then, Keystone is the one to use).

Comment: use keystone    https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18000/translate-arm-instructions-to-hex/18002#18002