# RISC-V assembler with strong Python support?

Tags: capstone, risc-v, assembler

I'm using the Capstone disassembler for decoding a RISC-V ELF binary but need the ability to reassemble modifications that I'm making to it programmatically to accomplish a reverse-engineering goal. Ideally, this would be an assembler that takes Capstone syntax or represents the assembly data in a similar structure. I know someone has previously ([Capstone in reverse mode](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/capstone-in-reverse-mode)) asked whether there's a Capstone-like project for assembling code. My question is, are there any Capstone-like assemblers which also have good RISC-V support?